# In Python is there a function for the "in" operator

Tags: python, function, operators

Is there any Python function for the "in" operator like what we have for operator.lt, operator.gt, ..
I wan't to use this function to do something like:

```
operator.in(5, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
>> True

operator.in(10, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
>> False
```

Comment: I dont understand why you would want to add the overhead of an import when a simple a in b would work wherever you would use this.

Comment: @gkusner: I'm not sure what the case is here, but if you want to use this in a callback you'd need a function, not a built-in operator.

Comment: Hence the question - in the problem as stated there would be no need for a function

Comment: @gkusner: Distilling your question down to the simplest-to-understand part is a very useful approach to SO.  We don't need to know why the OP wants this - the question is clear (and also makes it clear that they are aware of the `in` operator) and concise.  Would you rather the OP posted 50 lines of code and then asked how to make it work in a function callback, instead of just distilling down the problem to the essence here?

Comment: Actually I was asking the question for my own information - I wanted to understand the use case where this might be necessary - certainly the callback is one I was just trying to understand if there might be others where it might actually be useful/needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, use [`operator.contains()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.contains); note that the order of operands is reversed:

```
>>> import operator
>>> operator.contains([1,2,3,4,5,6], 5)
True
>>> operator.contains([1,2,3,4,5,6], 10)
False
```

You may have missed the handy [mapping table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) at the bottom of the documentation.